# Topological K-Theory-Spectrum for $C^*$-Algebras

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory, k-theory

I am currently reading up on K-theory and I am a bit confused by the definition of the topological K-Theory-spectrum for C*-algebras. It is mentioned in many articles as basic, but I can only find one definition which I am  confused by. It goes like this: Let A be a $C^*$-algebra. The topoligcal K-spectrum $K^{top}(A)$ is the spectrum where every second space is $$GL(A)=\text{colim}GL_n(A).$$ 
The spectrum is then given by homotopy-equivalences
$$K_0(A) \times BGL(A)\rightarrow \Omega GL(A)$$
and
$$GL(A) \rightarrow \Omega (BGL(A))=\Omega (K_0(A) \times BGL(A))$$
that arise from the Bott periodicity theorem.

I want to understand how this agrees with the definition of a spectrum as can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(topology)). So if every second space is GL(A), what are the other spaces. What are the base points and the structure maps? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The odd-level spaces are given by $\Omega GL(A)$.  The structure map $\Sigma K(A)_{2n-1} \to K(A)_{2n}$ is adjoint to the identity map $K(A)_{2n-1} = \Omega GL(A) \xrightarrow{=} \Omega GL(A) = \Omega K(A)_{2n}$.  The structure map $\Sigma K(A)_{2n} \to K(A)_{2n+1}$ is adjoint to the map $$K(A)_{2n} = GL(A) \to \Omega(K_0(A) \times BGL(A)) \to \Omega(\Omega GL(A)) = \Omega K(A)_{2n+1}$$ where the first map is the second homotopy equivalence you listed and the second is the loop of the first homotopy equivalence.